# Is there a safe way of converting a Collection to a sequence in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

Good afternoon, all!

So I've been playing around with ways of casting a .NET Collection to a functional data structure. The best I've been able to get is to cast it to a seq first and to whatever I want after that.

The problem is that this seems to break type inference, which is obviously unsafe.

Example:

```
let a = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("<query>") in
let entries = a.FindAll ()
let entries_list = 
     let (entries_seq : seq<obj>) = Seq.cast entries_list in
     Seq.toList entries_Seq
in
entries_list (* list of AD objects found from query, has type obj *)
```

In order to do anything useful with entries_list, I'd have to do:

```
entries_list :?> SearchResult
```

Trying to generalise it to a seq<'a> fails, since the compiler still requires that I statically type its enumerator (which makes sense).

Is there any way of avoiding this? I'm starting to think this is a limitation of using .NET data structures in a functional manner.

Sorry if this is a novice question; I'm green to F# and functional programming in general (and am loving it!). Cheers!

- Carlos.

Comment: Does doing `let entries_seq:seq<_> ...` work - this should give a strongly typed sequence

Comment: It didn't; I get a value restriction error, which is consistent with what I was seeing before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Daniel says, you typically shouldn't need to use `Seq.cast` because most collections will already implement the generic `seq<'t>` interface.  However, there are several .NET collection types that were built before the introduction of generics in .NET 2.0 which only implement the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface.  The F# compiler actually has some special logic in `for` loops called "enumerable extraction" to make working against these kinds of collections a bit easier.  Therefore, if you're only dealing with one of these collection types (e.g. you're working with `DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollections` a lot), then it probably makes sense to simply create a simple helper function:

```
let typedSearchResults (s:SearchResultCollection) =
    seq { for result in s -> result }
```

which you can then use instead of `Seq.cast` for this particular collection type.

If you're using lots of different old-style collections in the same project, then you can use some fancy F# features to make a generic `Seq.cast` alternative:

```
module Seq =
    let inline inferCast s = 
        // constrain ^t to have an Item indexed property (which we don't actually invoke)
        let _ = fun x -> (^t : (member Item : int -> ^v with get) (x, 0))
        let e = (^t : (member GetEnumerator : unit -> ^e) s)
        seq { while (^e : (member MoveNext : unit -> bool) e) do
                yield (^e : (member Current : obj) e) :?> ^v }
```

Now you can use `Seq.inferCast` instead of `Seq.cast`, and the correct item type will be inferred for you.  This is probably overkill in your case, though.

Comment: That actually might be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Daniel - technically, the way for loop enumerable extraction works, the "enumerable" might not really be an `IEnumerable` and the "enumerator" might not really be an `IEnumerator` - they can be any types supporting methods with the right names and signatures.  I was trying to mimic this behavior, but in the OP's example this flexibility isn't necessary.

Comment: @Daniel - However, the for loop behavior is still slightly different than mine. The way it works is that it uses the `Current` property directly if it has a non-`obj` type, and only looks for an `Item` indexed property otherwise. I think that you could do some additional trickery to make `inferCast` choose between the two patterns, but I tried to stick with a comprehensible definition.

Comment: Then `for` behaves differently than C#'s `foreach`? `foreach` doesn't use `Item` AFAIK.

Comment: @Daniel - indeed, this is an advantage of F#'s approach.  There is at least one other difference - the C# compiler prefers the pattern based approach while the F# compiler prefers calling through `IEnumerable<_>` (so a struct enumerator may be boxed in F# when it wouldn't be in C#, for instance).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken many BCL collections use `struct` `Enumerator`s to reduce allocation/reclamation. Since F# prefers boxing did the F# team decide that's no longer a worthwhile concern?

Comment: @Daniel - I'm not sure what the rationale was, but things like LINQ (or the functions in the `Seq` module) always use the `IEnumerable<_>` interface anyway, so it's probably not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

Most .NET collections implement `IEnumerable<T>` (aliased as `seq<'T>` in F#) but occasionally you'll run across one that only implements the non-generic interface `IEnumerable`. `SearchResultCollection` is one such type. You can use `Seq.cast` to convert those collections to `seq<'T>`, making it possible to use them with functions in the `Seq` module.

```
open System.DirectoryServices

use searcher = new DirectorySearcher("<query>")
let entries = searcher.FindAll() |> Seq.cast<SearchResult>
let entries_list = Seq.toList entries
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

I get that much, but how do I generalise this for all such collections? It seems like I can't without doing a lot of static typing.

Carlos

Comment: Do you want `Seq.cast` but without requiring the type arg? Well, in many cases it can be inferred from later usage of the sequence. kvb gave an interesting solution, but even it has some restrictions.